# 403 - You are not authorised to view this resource. Error in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

When I click an article page Then Show the error message.

```
You may not be able to visit this page because of:

1. an out-of-date bookmark/favourite
2. a search engine that has an out-of-date listing for this site
3. a mistyped address
4. you have no access to this page
5. The requested resource was not found.
6. An error has occurred while processing your request.

Please try one of the following pages:

Home Page

If difficulties persist, please contact the System Administrator of this site.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong permissions set on Joomla's folder or the index.php of Joomla. Check the permissions, make sure that Apache can read the Joomla folder.

Comment: Where to set permission . I am first time in Joomla.

Comment: You can set permissions at the component level from the joomla administrator interface. Log in to the back end of the site as administrator, go to the global configuration and click Articles on the left. You can edit permissions under the permission tab.

Comment: @larpo Not see the Articles in Global Configuration

Comment: I'm talking about the filesystem permissions - this has nothing to do with your global configuration file.